# GnuPG em PHP5 não imprime em browser, mas funciona em terminal?

Tags: php, linha-de-comando

Estou tendo um problema no PHP que nunca presenciei antes, estou usando a classe GnuPG para gerar mensagens criptografadas, porem não consigo utilizar em browser, fiquei pensando no porquê mas não chego a conclusão, talvez segurança, a variável gerada sempre fica vazia no navegador, mas no terminal é imprimido perfeitamente.

Código:

```
<?php

  $text = "ISSO É UM TESTE";

  $enc = encrypt($text);

  print $enc;

  function encrypt($text){
      $gpg = new gnupg();
      $gpg->addencryptkey("KEY_AQUI");
      $enc = $gpg->encrypt("$text");
      return $enc;
  }

?>
```

No browser, simplesmente não funciona, a página fica em branco, no terminal consigo resultados, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: O texto é criptografado normalmente]

Comment: Boa tarde, poste o código inteiro do index.php que você executou no terminal (se puder simplifique), leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - fico aguardando você editar a tua pergunta e colocar o código nela, tenho certeza que vai levar meu comentário como uma critica construtiva :)

Comment: Obrigado por responder, bem, o código é basicamente o que já tinha mostrado, fiz as alterações, o código que tenho até agora é esse.

Comment: `gnupg` é importado como? Ou esta classe é provida de uma extensão pra php `extension=foo.so`?

Comment: sim, vem de uma extensão (./usr/lib/php5/20131226/gnupg.so) , instalei normalmente pelo apt (linux)

Comment: Tu baixou pelo repositorio do ubuntu? Ou você adicionou algum repositorio? Minha maquina virtual Debian ta em outro PC, mas assim que possivel irei testar.

Comment: baixei pelo oficial mesmo (debian)

Comment: Legal, não sei quando vou conseguir testar, mas assim que possivel te dou um feedback